# Process a list of lists, finding all lists that have matching last values?

Tags: python, set, intersection

Given a list of lists

```
lol = [[0,a], [0,b],
       [1,b], [1,c],
       [2,d], [2,e],
       [2,g], [2,b],
       [3,e], [3,f]]
```

I would like to extract all sublists that have the same last element (`lol[n][1]`) and end up with something like below:

```
[0,b]
[1.b]
[2,b]
[2,e]
[3,e]
```

I know that given two lists we can use an intersection, what is the right way to go about a problem like this, other than incrementing the index value in a for each loop?

Comment: Go through each sub-list inside the list: Extract the last element of the sub-list ('a`, `b` in your example), and append it to a dictionary of list with the extracted element. Eg `{'a': [[0, 'a']], 'b': [[0, 'b'],[1, 'b']]}`.

Comment: I have added multiple ways you can do this in a pythonic way. Do check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Using collections.defaultdict

You can use `defaultdict` to the first group up your items with more than one occurrence, then, iterate over the `dict.items` to get what you need.

```
from collections import defaultdict


lol = [[0,'a'], [0,'b'],
       [1,'b'], [1,'c'],
       [2,'d'], [2,'e'],
       [2,'g'], [2,'b'],
       [3,'e'], [3,'f']]


d = defaultdict(list)

for v,k in lol:
    d[k].append(v)

# d looks like - 
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'a': [0],
#              'b': [0, 1, 2],
#              'c': [1],
#              'd': [2],
#              'e': [2, 3],
#              'g': [2],
#              'f': [3]})
    
result = [[v,k] for k,vs in d.items() for v in vs if len(vs)>1]
print(result)
```

```
[[0, 'b'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'b'], [2, 'e'], [3, 'e']]
```

---

#### 2. Using pandas.duplicated

Here is how you can do this with Pandas -

1. Convert to pandas dataframe
2. For key column, find the duplicates and keep all of them
3. Convert to list of records while ignoring index

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(lol, columns=['val','key'])
dups = df[df['key'].duplicated(keep=False)]
result = list(dups.to_records(index=False))
print(result)
```

```
[(0, 'b'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'e'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'e')]
```

---

#### 3. Using numpy.unique

You can solve this in a vectorized manner using numpy -

0. Convert to numpy matrix `arr`
1. Find unique elements `u` and their counts `c`
2. Filter list of unique elements that occur more than once `dup`
3. Use broadcasting to compare the second column of the array and take any over axis=0 to get a boolean which is True for duplicated rows
4. Filter the `arr` based on this boolean

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(lol)

u, c = np.unique(arr[:,1], return_counts=True)
dup = u[c > 1]

result = arr[(arr[:,1]==dup[:,None]).any(0)]
result
```

```
array([['0', 'b'],
       ['1', 'b'],
       ['2', 'e'],
       ['2', 'b'],
       ['3', 'e']], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining this line, What do you call this type of linear nesting? I assume that k,vs in d.item would be the outermost for loop if written as nested loops in a more traditional way?
result = [[v,k] for k,vs in d.items() for v in vs if len(vs)>1

Comment: Sure, check for `nested loops in list comprehension`. The general structure is `[item for sublist in list for item in sublist]` rather than `[item for item in sublist for sublist in list]`.

Comment: So i am iterating over the items in the grouped dictionary, and for each element in values of the dict (`vs` which is a list) , i am again iterating over the sublist to get `v`, with a condition that `len(vs)>1` for duplicates. Then i am simply coupling it with the corresponding `k` and returning it as a list of lists.

Comment: Hope that clarifies what you asked. Let me know if any confusion. Also, do feel free to mark the answer if it helped solve your query. Thanks!